# Visual Studio shuts down repeatedly when formatting code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting

"Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working"

I format my code constantly using Ctrl E + D. Sometimes this works, sometimes it causes Visual Studio to shut down. I can't pinpoint exactly why it does this. Perhaps it's a setting that I'm missing (or accidentally changed)? My work computer never does this. This is my personal computer.

**This happens 99% of the time on Views, not code in classes, CSS, or js**. I've attempted to make sure that my HTML/code is correct (no red underlines or green "for HTML") when formatting, hoping that this solves the problem. I can format code on a view, then on the same view, format again (after some changes), and it'll (VS) shut down.

Does this happen to anyone else?

- Windows 8
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- WebEssentials

---

- I don't have ReSharper installed.
- I have enough memory
- CPU isn't 100%

Answer (score 0):

its probably a memory problem,Please clear your **recent,%temp%** and **temp** files by run command

Afirst of all **close all windows**.

eg:In windows press **start+r** -->run command window appears

Then type **recent** and **hit enter**.Then select all and delete all files

then type **%temp%** and do same process,and also delete **temp** folder

If same problem exists re-install your software.